# Is "/var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kadm5.acl" the only way to specify administrators in kerberos?

Tags: kerberos

The documentation for RHEL explains how to make users administrators through the `/var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kadm5.acl` file, but does not specify if this is the only way to do this. Are there any other ways to specify principals with administrative permissions in kerberos?

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/managing_smart_cards/configuring_a_kerberos_5_server#Setting_Up_Secondary_KDCs

Answer (score 1):

The *acl_file* (kadm5.acl by default) is not the only way to specify kerberos administrators. It also can be achieved via *kadm5_auth interface*:

> The ACL file can coexist with other authorization modules in release
>   1.16 and later, as configured in the [kadm5_auth interface](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-latest/doc/admin/conf_files/krb5_conf.html#kadm5-auth) section of krb5.conf. The ACL file will positively authorize operations according
>   to the rules above, but will never authoritatively deny an operation,
>   so other modules can authorize operations in addition to those
>   authorized by the ACL file.

Source: [MIT Kerberos Documentation](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-latest/doc/admin/conf_files/kadm5_acl.html)